# How to create token entirely by InfluxDB API

Tags: influxdb

I can generate InfluxDB token by client -- `influx auth create --all-access`.

InfluxDB API doc tells that exists endpoint /api/v2/authorizations to generate token which seems to be recursive because it requires yet another token.

Is it possible to generate new InfluxDB token by API without such recursion?